# Getting an error message when trying to use the R describe function

Tags: r, describe

The function was not recognized by auto completion, so I run a command for documentation:

```
?describe
```

and got the following output:

```
No documentation for ‘describe’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??describe’
```

When I ran `??describe` I got the following output:

```
Help pages:
dbplyr::db_connection_describe      Miscellaneous database generics
dplyr::dim_desc     Describing dimensions
httr::oauth_endpoint        Describe an OAuth endpoint.
grid::arrow     Describe arrows to add to a line.
grid::grobWidth     Create a Unit Describing the Width of a Grob
grid::grobX     Create a Unit Describing a Grob Boundary Location
grid::stringWidth       Create a Unit Describing the Width and Height of a String or Math Expression
```

Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It's from the `psych` package which you might want to install. Or try `str` or `summary` instead, they are not too bad!

Comment: `psych` in not recognized either, but `str` and `summary` worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: If the package is not installed, it's hard to be recognized ;) Use `install.packages('psych')` if you want it, then try again the search.

Comment: I tried installing it. I think the issue was that I didn't use quotation marks. Thanks.

Comment: ...and (like all packages) install it one time, but when you want to use it load it first with `library(psych)`.